# how to fix strtok compiler error?

Tags: c++, c

hi so i am writing this code to to look into a text file and put each word it finds in a c string array. I was able to write the code but I get problems when there is a mistake in the actual text file. for example my program would crash if there is a double space in the sentence like "the car  goes fast" it would stop at car. looking at my code i believe that this is because of strtok. i think to fix the problem i need to make strtok make a token of then next value but i am not sure how to do so

my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   ifstream file;
   file.open("text.txt");
   string line;

   char * wordList[10000];
   int x=0;

   while (getline(file,line)){

      // initialize a sentence
      char *sentence = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*line.length());
      strcpy(sentence,line.c_str());

      // intialize a pointer
     char* word;

      // this gives us a pointer to the first instance of a space, comma, etc.,   
      // that is, the characters in "sentence" will be read into "word" 
      // until it reaches   one of the token characters (space, comma, etc.)
     word = strtok(sentence, " ,!;:.?");

      // now we can utilize a while loop, so every time the sentence comes to a new 
      // token character, it stops, and "word" will equal the characters from the last
      // token character to the new character, giving you each word in the sentence

      while (NULL != word){
         wordList[x]=word;
         printf("%s\n", wordList[x]);
         x++;
         word = strtok(NULL," ,!;:.?");
      }
    }
    printf("done");
    return 0;
}
```

I know some of the code is in c++ and some is in c but I am trying to do the most of it in c

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are not allocating enough space for a null terminated string.

```
  char *sentence = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*line.length());
  strcpy(sentence,line.c_str());
```

If you need to capture `"abc"`, you need 3 elements for the characters and another one for the terminating null character, i.e. 4 characters total.

The value of the argument to `malloc` needs to be increased by 1.

```
  char *sentence = (char*) malloc(line.length()+1);
  strcpy(sentence,line.c_str());
```

It's not clear why you are using `malloc` in a C++ program. I suggest use `new`.

```
  char *sentence = new char[line.length()+1];
  strcpy(sentence,line.c_str());
```

Comment: the professor mix and match c++ and c, but it is supposed to be a c class. so i really don't now a lot about c++.

Comment: @alex, try to stick to one as much as you can, if your professor does not mind which one you use.

Comment: i actually tested the file that it is supposed to read and the problem is that is breaks down when the values it supposed to turn to null ass in consecutive order like a double space or is two words have only a period in between them.

Comment: @R Sahu I honestly hate that I have to do that but the professor flip flop what he teaches and what he gives us in examples. i think the majority of his examples are in c++